# Perl's REST Client error when trying to use Crontab

Tags: json, perl, rest, rest-client

Script works well when run manually, but when I schdule it in cronjob it shows :

```
malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "<html>\r\n<head><tit...") at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/JSON.pm line 171.
```

script itself:

```
#rest config vaiables


$ENV{'PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_NONE'} = 0;
print "test\n";
my $client = REST::Client->new();
$client->addHeader('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46cmFyaXRhbg==');
$client->addHeader('content_type', 'application/json');
$client->addHeader('accept', 'application/json');
$client->setHost('http://10.10.10.10');
$client->setTimeout(1000);

$useragent = $client->getUseragent();

print "test\n";

#Getting racks by pod
                 $req = '/api/v2/racks?name_like=2t';
               #print " rekvest {$req}\n";
               $client->request('GET', qq($req));
               $racks = from_json($client->responseContent());
               $datadump = Dumper (from_json($client->responseContent()));
```

crontab -l

```
*/2 * * * *  /usr/local/bin/perl /folder/api/2t.pl > /dmitry/api/damnitout 2>&1
```

Appreciate any suggestion
Thank you,
Dmitry

Comment: Well, the response content is obviously HTML, not JSON. And you're missing `use warnings; use strict;`.

Comment: without that  it will not work? use warnings; use strict;.

Comment: What source are you learning Perl from?

Comment: Learning Perl, O'reilly
Perl Cookbook 
Sombody else's code
Though I don't know how this answe will help me in this particular question.
My question was a little rethorical, I know it will work , I don't care about strict, but there were warnings, that I deleted when I was troubleshooting this script. To exclude possibility of warnings of interrupting of the running of the script

Comment: So ... you don't care about strict, and instead of fixing the problems pointed out by the warnings, you just disabled warnings instead? Good luck with your code.

Comment: Warnings pointed me to usage of undefined variables and that's the part of logic. Nothing more, added warnings , it would not help. Anyway thanks for your time Muse of Tragedy :)

Comment: well, it seems likely that the response isn't json;  how about printing it and seeing what it *is*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to say what is really happening, but in my experience 99% issues of running stuff in `crontab` stems from differences in environment variables.

Typical way to debug this: in the beginning of your script add block like this:

```
foreach my $key (keys %ENV) {
    print "$key = $ENV{$key}\n";
}
```

Run it in console, look at the output, save it in log file.

Now, repeat the same in crontab and save it into log file (you have already done that - this is good).

See if there is any difference in environment variables when trying to run it both ways and try to fix it. In Perl, probably easiest is to alter environment by changing %ENV. After all differences are sorted out, there is no reason for this to not work right.

Good luck!

Comment: , added `ENV{'PATH'} = '/root/local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/opt/python2.6/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/.rvm/bin:/root/bin';` to the script , still have problem , no errors now , but it does not work...

Comment: Make sure that ALL environment variables are exactly the same whether you run it from console or from cron. Also, be sure that script is called using the same Perl interpreter. It helps to set proper shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/perl` or what have you) and make script executable (`chmod +x myscript.pl`)

Comment: You are right , I am not sure what $ENV was the the problem , just copied them all, created list by 
    `foreach my $key (keys %ENV) {

  $env = '$ENV{'."$key".'} = \''."$ENV{$key}".'\';';
  
    print "$env\n";
    }`